# Why does this SQL Alchemy CASE statement give me an error

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following statement in my python

```py
            case(
                [
                    (Table.c.start_date > "2023-10-04")
                    | (Table.c.end_date < "2023-10-01", 0)
                ],
                else_=(
                    func.date_part(
                        "day",
                        func.least(Table.c.end_date, "2023-10-04")
                        - func.greatest(Table.c.start_date, "2023-10-01"),
                    )
                    + 1
                ),
            ).label("active_days"),
```

I am trying to replicate the following PostgreSQL

```sql
            CASE 
                WHEN Table.start_date > '2023-10-04' OR Table.end_date < '2023-10-02' THEN 0
                ELSE DATE_PART('day', LEAST(Table.end_date, '2023-10-04') - GREATEST(Table.start_date, '2023-10-02')) + 1
            END AS active_days
```

However I am getting the following error back in relation to the 3rd line down on the python snippet. The SQL works as desired, I am using SQLAlchemy 1.3

```
SQL expression for WHERE/HAVING role expected, got (<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7f3e291b0c10>, 0).
```

Comment: The `,0` is in the wrong place, it should be just before the closing list bracket (`]`) and outside of the `end_date` comparison.  The clue is ` (<sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x7f3e291b0c10>, 0)` is a tuple of the comparison, which is a `BinaryExpression` instance, and `0`.